# Program skips code after trying to parse XML in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to parse some XML (html) I downloaded using WebRequest.Create() and then read it. However after loading the XML file using LoadXml(string), anything else I execute doesn't work. Setting a breakpoint on anything afterwards doesn't work and it doesn't break.

I tried catching exception but none are occurring, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(HTTPResponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim xDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        xDoc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd())
        Dim omfg As String = xDoc.ChildNodes().Item(0).InnerText()
        Dim name As XmlNodeList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        Dim jj As Integer = name.Count
        For i As Integer = 0 To name.Count - 1
            MessageBox.Show(name.Item(i).InnerText)
        Next i
```

Anything after the "xDoc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd())" doesn't execute.. Any ideas on this?
My XML does have some whitespace at the beginning, I don't know if that is causing the problem...

Comment: do you receive any error message?  is the code in a try catch block that doesn't do anything with the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but it's throwing an exception because the html you download isn't well-formed xml, and you have a high-level try catch block hiding the error from you.

Comment: Hmm you're right. Is there any way I can find out whats wrong in the xml?

Comment: you should probably remove the try catch block, or debug.print the exception that is being caught.  probably would shed some light on the issue at least

Comment: @Bead - Unlike html, real xml is a very... picky format. Compliant xml parkers are supposed to treat anything not perfect as a fatal error.  It can be very tricky to use an xml parser on a real world html document.